pandas merge dataframe but keep out columns the same
Current code output two columns *_x and *_y if column name the same, what I want is keep the second dataframe to overwrite first dataframe
for example:
import pandas as pd

data1 = [
    ['A', 10],
    ['B', 11],
    ['C', 12],
    ['D', 13]
    ]
data2 = [
    ['B', 2],
    ['D', 3]
    ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['name', 'value'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['name', 'value'])

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name', how='outer')
print(df3)

Current output is:
  name  value_x  value_y
0    A       10      NaN
1    B       11      2.0
2    C       12      NaN
3    D       13      3.0

Expected:
  name  value
0    A     10
1    B     2
2    C     12
3    D     3

Just like use second dataframe to overwrite first dataframe. if any other method better than merge?

Try combine_first():
df2.set_index('name').combine_first(df1.set_index('name')).reset_index()

Output:
  name  value
0    A     10
1    B      2
2    C     12
3    D      3


Another possible solution, which combines the two dataframes, by stacking them vertically (concat), and then removes duplicate entries based on the name column (drop_duplicates). It retains only the last occurrence of each duplicate, ensuring that the resulting dataframe contains unique names with their most recent associated data.
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep='last')

Output:
  name  value
0    A     10
2    C     12
0    B      2
1    D      3


import pandas as pd

data1 = [
    ['A', 10],
    ['B', 11],
    ['C', 12],
    ['D', 13]
]
data2 = [
    ['B', 2],
    ['D', 3]
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['name', 'value'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['name', 'value'])

# Merge the dataframes on 'name' with an outer join
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name', how='outer', suffixes=('_x', '_y'))

# Use combine_first to get the desired 'value' column and convert to int
df3['value'] = df3['value_y'].combine_first(df3['value_x']).astype(int)

# Drop the unnecessary columns
df3 = df3[['name', 'value']]

print(df3)

Output :
name  value
0    A     10
1    B      2
2    C     12
3    D      3

